# Current branch in a detached state

Tags: git, branch, alias

There are several potential ways to get the name of the current branch:

```
current-branch1 = name-rev --name-only HEAD
current-branch2 = branch --show-current
```

The #1 does not work correctly in the presence of tags...

#2 does work better... except when HEAD points to a detached state.

Is there a better alias to know onto which branch the commit was done in a detached state?  In other words, one alias that would work better in all cases?

**UPDATE --** When checking out a commit, I'd like to get the name of the branch the commit was done onto...

```
$ g co 2767c5f9
Note: switching to '2767c5f9'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in 
this state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
[...]
HEAD is now at 2767c5f9 Update ChangeLog

$ git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --points-at HEAD refs/heads
```

The last command returns nothing...

Comment: The "detached HEAD" state means, quite literally, that you are on no branch. Being "on a branch" means that `HEAD` is attached to a branch name. When `HEAD` is not attached to a branch name, there is no branch name. You can't get something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Git does not store the name of the branch on which a commit was made, because Git does not consider branch names important or relevant. Don't even try to ask this, says Git. It's not useful: if it has any value, the value is negative, not positive (i.e., it makes things *worse* to know which branch you were on at the time).

Comment: @torek, thanks for the explanations. I don't understand why it's not foreseen nor good to know on which branch I was when I made a commit, but that clarifies the answers!

Comment: It took some time, but I eventually came to agree with Linus Torvalds that the branch name has negative value, not positive value ... *unless* the branch name encodes something semantic. In that case you might want a prepare-commit-msg hook that copies the branch name into a prepared commit message. But in general you want something meaningful about the commit, and "which branch this was on" isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is :

```
# any ref (branch or tag or remote branch or ...)
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --points-at HEAD

# branches only :
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --points-at HEAD refs/heads
```

caveat : if several refs/branches point at the current commit, the above commands will list them all.

---

*[edit]* `git name-rev` also has a [`--refs` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-name-rev#Documentation/git-name-rev.txt---refsltpatterngt), you just have to know that branches are references starting with `refs/heads` :

```
git name-rev --name-only --refs="refs/heads/*" HEAD
```

Comment: Hi @LeGEC. Your commands do not behave better than current-branch2. Are they still somehow better?

Comment: from your question : I thought you meant "name any branch that currently points *exactly* at my current commit". Otherwise : try `git branch --contains` or `git for-each-ref --contains`

Comment: Any comment on whether `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" --points-at HEAD refs/heads` or my alias #2 is better?